# How can East Asian language input work properly on a SWF in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash, ibus

I want to input CJK (Chinese, Janpanese, Korean) languages on an SWF file played with Firefox, but it accepts only text in the Latin alphabet.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

What causes this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I want to know that you use what plugin to play swf in firefox.

Comment: Plugin is Adobe Flash Player - Version: 13.0.0.182.

Comment: I think that adobe flash player doesn't support chromium since 2014/04. I suggest you reference it at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/chromium-npapi-flash-dropped-april-2014.

Comment: I checked it. You are right. Is there any alternatives that I could use?